# How to set shadow gradient image on UIImageView iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gradient, shadow

Hey I'm new to iPhone and I have been trying to set shadow for `UIImageView` using shadow gradient image i.e. "Image-Shadow.png" using below code.

```
    imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage 
    imageNamed:@"Image-Shadow.png"]].CGColor;

    imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

My problem is, i am not getting shadow in my `UIImageView` using above code. Can you please tell me that is this the correct way to add shadow image in `UIImageView` or it is possible with some other way?

Comment: imageView.clipsToBounds = NO; make it as YES and try and let me know result....

Comment: Thanks @Spynet I have set it to YES.. but still my problem is same.

Comment: _imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, -3);
    _imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution as per my requirement :

```
//set shadow gradient on image view

UIView *shadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame]; //add view behind the image view

shadowView.layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-Shadow.png"].CGImage;

[imageView addSubview:shadowView];
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the image. I don't think you can provide a pattern image to create a shadow!
Give a proper color like `[UIColor blackColor].CGColor` and it should work.

Comment: @AdithyaThanks.. using [UIColor blackColor].CGColor it's working. But need to add image for shadow gradient as per my requirement. I don't know what my tester wants from me :)

Comment: Add another imageview behind the first imageview with a slightly bigger frame? Add shadow image to that.

Comment: Can you please tell me that i am testing on simulator, not on my device. Is this the reason that i am not getting shadow gradient in my imageview?

Comment: No that should not be a prob

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

where you are setting the shadow, but not giving it a visible space to display itself.
Positive or negative values should be given to both parameters.
Positive values stretch "down" and "to the right" of your view, negative values stretch "to the left" and "to the up" of your view.

Comment: what you want to tell, should i need to remove this given shadowOffSet property in my code?